# Не работает сайт через ipv6 (502, nginx)

Tags: nginx, debian, ipv6

Здравствуйте.

Я добавил AAAA записи для домена, настроил веб сервер nginx следующим образом:

```
server {
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  root /var/www/default;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

default:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
  server_name localhost;

  root /var/www/default;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ^~ /pma/ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ /pma(/.*\.php) {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME localhost;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
  }
}
```

Но сайт все равно не работает, отдает ошибку 502. Хостеры говорят, что у меня не добавлен адрес на сервер, но я не совсем понимаю куда его добавлять, ipv6 настраиваю первый раз.

Comment: Во-первых, отдаёт ошибку 502 кто? Во-вторых, вы ждали час-другой после добавления записей?

Comment: @andreymal сайт долго грузит и потом отдаёт 502, жду уже часа 3

Comment: На вопрос не ответили, отдаёт ошибку 502 кто? Ошибку 502 может отдать только работающий сервер, значит на пути к вашему сайту он где-то запущен и успешно работает. Ваш хостер предоставляет реверс-прокси для вашего nginx или ошибку 502 отдаёт всё-таки именно ваш nginx? Или провайдер у вашего интернета, через который вы открываете сайт, поставил свой собственный прокси, который и отдаёт ошибку 502? Конфигурация вашего nginx точно-точно именно такая, как в вопросе (не считая server_name) и никаких других секций server у вас точно-точно нет (в других файлах, например)? В общем, мало подробностей:)

Comment: У вас получается подключиться к вашему серверу по IPv6 другими путсями, через ssh или ftp например?

Comment: у меня свой vps. есть доступ через ssh. про перенаправлений нету, есть еще один конфиг (default): отредактировал вопрос, можете его посмотреть, другого ничего нету.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь открыть не pma хоть?

Comment: А вообще с таким конфигом nginx вроде как не может отдавать ошибку 502, не понимаю что происходит. Если у вас есть доступ к ssh, error.log читали?

Comment: error log nginx'a?

Comment: начните читать с [этого](https://version6.ru/#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Проверьте, работает ли php-fpm.